# Transposing database with combination data

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

how do I get from what I have to what I want in this scenario?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use Power Pivot.  It has an UnPivot method.

Comment: Welcome! Do you know about PowerQuery? Search it on the Data tab. [**Just some clicks and get result - YouTube**](https://youtu.be/Kbu5RkUo6-k)

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Comment: Thanks all. What I would like is to keep the Site and Line item reference, but to transform the last 2 fields (i.e. have date and the respective revenue values in column format).

Comment: What was wrong with the suggestions made?  (Power Pivot and/or Power Query)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Power Query:

1. Selece the Range and go to **Data**- **From Table/Range**- open the **Power Query editor**:

[image]

2. Under **Power Query Editor**- select the **Column 21-Jan, Column 21-Feb and Column 21-Mar**- go to **Transform** Tab- select **Unpivot Columns**:

[image]

3. Change the Columns name to **Column Date** and **Column Value**- change the **Date format**- **Close and Load**:

[image]